# query for items during a certain period

Tags: vb.net

There is a table showing the types of medicines and the serial for each type of medicine.
There is a column for the quantity received from the item and another for the quantity spent from the item.
There is a column for the date and the last boolean value to delete and hide the element by not setting true

database access 2010 code vb.net .

Table:
MEDICALCOME_TB

column
MEDICALCOME_CODE : Item Code
MEDICALCOME_SERIAL : Company serial
MEDICALCOME_NAME : Item name
MEDICALCOME_COM :Incoming quantity
MEDICALCOME_LEAVE :outgoing quantity
MEDICALCOME_DATE :DATE
MEDICALCOME_CHECK : Checking a boolean value to use by deleting and archiving

I want to sum the period between two dates DateTimePicker - for the total incoming - and outgoing - and the difference between the incoming and outgoing remaining

I used the following code to search and group between two different date periods. Nothing appears

```
Dim A = Format(DATETIM_START.Value, "yyyy/dd/MM")

Dim B = Format(DATETIM_END.Value, "yyyy/dd/MM")

Dim DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_CODE, MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_SERIAL, Sum(MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_COM) As SumOfMEDICALCOME_COM, Sum(MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_LEAVE) As SumOfMEDICALCOME_LEAVE
From MEDICALCOME_TB
Where (((MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_CHECK) = True) And ((MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_DATE)between #" & B & "# And #" & A & "#))
Group By MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_CODE, MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_SERIAL ;", con)
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the SQL query and running it directly on the database? Also please don't concatenate strings to form a query (especially with dates). Look up how to parameterize your queries, and pass the Date objects in as actual dates, don't convert them to strings. Also, what do you do with your DataAdapter?

Comment: hi slugsie I ran the query inside Access and it didn't work.

Comment: Then the problem is with your query, not in VB.Net.

Comment: yes I know the problem is with the query. But what is the solution?

Comment: Parameterize the query, and don't format dates as strings. My first concern is that while you're formatting the dates in yyyy/dd/MM, you don't know that Access is interpreting them that way. It might think they're yyyy/MM/dd so that would be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameterize the query and pass dates in as date objects

```
Dim DataAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_CODE, MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_SERIAL, Sum(MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_COM) As SumOfMEDICALCOME_COM, Sum(MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_LEAVE) As SumOfMEDICALCOME_LEAVE From MEDICALCOME_TB Where (((MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_CHECK) = True) And ((MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_DATE) between ? AND ?)) Group By MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_CODE, MEDICALCOME_TB.MEDICALCOME_SERIAL ;", con)

DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@StartDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DATETIM_Start.Value)
DataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@EndDate", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DATETIM_END.Value)
```

That's from memory, but should be close enough to get you going.
See here for more:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2